# How to determine if NFS mount is mounted as v3 or v4?

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, acl

Red Hat 5/6 when I do mount it says type nfs, I would like to know how to determine version if it isn't listed in mount options or fstab.  Please don't say remount it with the version option, I want to know how to determine the currently mounted NFS version.  I am guessing it will default based on NFS server/client settings, but how to I determine what it is currently?  I am pretty sure it's NFS v3 because nfs4_setfacl is not supported it seems.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Here are 2 ways to do it:

#### mount

Using mount's `-v` switch:

```
$ mount -v | grep /home/sam
mulder:/export/raid1/home/sam on /home/sam type nfs (rw,intr,tcp,nfsvers=3,rsize=16384,wsize=16384,addr=192.168.1.1)
```

#### nfsstat

Using `nfsstat -m`:

```
$ nfsstat -m | grep -A 1 /home/sam
/home/sam from mulder:/export/raid1/home/sam
 Flags: rw,vers=3,rsize=16384,wsize=16384,hard,intr,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,addr=mulder
```

Comment: Worth noting, sometimes `nfsstat -m` shows version and more details when `mount -v` does not.

Comment: how would you check the version on server side ?

Answer (score 33):

Use `nfsstat -m` it will display all the nfs mounted filesystem and theirs properties.

Comment: I liked your answer but gave it to slm because he provided more information.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it contained less information, and answered the question perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget the ultimate authority!

```
cat /proc/mounts
```

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu 12.04, `mount -v` has the same information than without `-v` (no NFS version).

`nfsstat -m` shows the information about version.

Answer (score 2):

Just plain

```
nfsstat
```

On the master server worked for me --

```
Server nfs v3:
```

Using -m only worked on the slaves

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22.04.1 Jammy at least the most sure shot way is

`sudo cat /proc/fs/nfsd/versions`

which yields something like

`-2 +3 +4 +4.1 +4.2`

Answer (score -2):

df -T

This will show filesystem.

Comment: Does it show NFS version information, as required by the OP? Please [edit] and update your answer with an example of the command's output.